# Use toggle() with css on multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple divs of varying heights that need to be toggle-able, each of these divs has the same class. What is the best way of accomplishing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/hS6RH/41/

```
$('.smallify').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).parent('.container').css('height', '');) {
        $(this).parent('.container').css('height', '20px');
    } else {
        $(this).parent('.container').css('height', '');
});
```

Comment: Add a class that changes the height to 20px then just use toggleClass with that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't too clear, but this is probably what you are looking for (based on your jsFiddle)

```
$('.smallify').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/zsh6U/

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should do it:

```
$('.smallify').on('click', function() {
    $("ul", $(this).parent('.container')).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with toggling the class:

```
$('.smallify').on('click', function() {
   $(this).closest('.container').toggleClass('full');
});
```

and css class is:

```
.full{height:300px;}
```